# SQL Query (Oracle) - Select closest date to a given date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with different attributes:

```
**attr       date       price**
tv         01.07.19     5
tv         05.06.19     3,5
tv         03.04.19     2
music      05.06.19     7
music      02.05.19     6
mobile     01.01.19     4 
mobile     12.12.18     8
```

With the parameter "pDate", I want to select the value for an attribute to a 
E.g. pDate = '15.06.19'

The output should look like this:

```
attr       date       price
tv         01.06.19     5
music      05.06.19     7
mobile     01.01.19     4
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT attr
       , date
       , price 
FROM table 
WHERE date <= 'pDate' 
ORDER BY Row_number() OVER ( partition BY attr ORDER BY date DESC);
```

Comment: OK. what have you attempted?

Comment: SELECT attr, date, price
FROM   table
WHERE  date <= 'pDate'
ORDER  BY Row_number() 
            OVER ( 
              partition BY attr 
              ORDER BY date DESC);

Comment: Hi @HarM93 always add important information's to your question. Do that in a way that you click edit button under the question and do not write it in the comment. For example the code you have tried. I have added it for you this time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  For closest *before* or *after*:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by attr order by abs(date - :pdate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the closest date *on or before*, then:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by attr date desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where date <= :pdate
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  This will filter out `attr` values that have no "before" date.